# Angularjs isolate scope, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gsap

I'm trying to animate some buttons and I don't get it, why the isolate scope is not working. Here's a fiddle:

`Fiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/gLhveeor/4/

The mouseenter should only trigger the particular animation and not all of the ng-repeat items.

I hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not scope issue, you are just initializing `TimelineLite` object with HTMLCollection of elements and then run animation on all of them.  Instead select necessary element on mouseover like this:

```
.controller('myCtrl', function ($timeout, $scope) {
    $timeout(function () {

        var tl = new TimelineLite();
        tl.stop();

        $scope.play = function ($event) {
            var target = $event.target.querySelector('.foo-2');
            tl.to(target, 0.4, {x: 30});
            tl.play();
        };
    }, 0);
});
```

where in HTML you pass event object into handler:

```
<div my-directive class="foo" ng-mouseenter="play($event)">
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/gLhveeor/5/

However advice I can give you is to move this login into directive, having them in controller is not the best idea.

Comment: Tank you very much. That worked out for me! So you mean you would put that into a link function?

Comment: Yes, in directives link function.

Answer (score 0):

In your ng-repeat you're assigning the same class (`foo-2`) to both elements, so
`angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('foo-2'));`
matches 2 elements.

I assume this TimelineLite object can initialize itself onto several elements at once, so when you write:

```
tl.to($a1, 0.4, {x: 30});
```

`$a1` contains both matched elements, so `t1` will mean a collection of both of them, making `t1.play()` affect both.